# Ubuntu 20.04 multiple interfaces. How to select default interface

Tags: networking, gateway

I'm trying to set up Suricata on my Ubuntu box. I have a dedicated interface for it (enx00e04c681037). For some reason Ubuntu keeps trying to use this interface for all traffic. I found this out when my NFS shares were no longer mounting.

How do I make sure the enx00e04c681037 interface is doing nothing except receiving traffic from my router?

Thanks!

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.15/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.178.5
        search:
        - home.local
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.178.1
         metric: 50
         table: 101

    enx00e04c681037:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.14/24
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two interfaces of the same Ubuntu node with different addresses (.14 and .15) on the same IP subnet. This is always a source of problems. There are more possible solutions, here I offer two:

1. Deactivate one interface. Use only one for all traffic. Except for teaming or redundancy, there is no reason to use two interfaces on the same network.
2. Use a different network for each interface. For instance `192.168.178.14` and `192.168.200.15`. Carefully set both networks and the routing.